# I tried to create a footer stay bottom but it's not working

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

Here is how my page look like:

[image]

I tried to add `position: relative` to my PageContainer but the footer still right there. How can I fix it ?

Here is my code in App.js:

```
const PageContainer = styled.div`
  position: relative;
`;

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <PageContainer>
        <TopNav />
        <SideNav />
        <RouterStyle>
          <Router>
            <ContactForm path="/contact" />
            <ShopAllProducts path="/" />
            <NewArrival path="/shop/new-arrival" />
            <Product path="/product/:title_url" />
          </Router>
        </RouterStyle>
      </PageContainer>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}
```

here is my `Footer.js`:

```
const FooterWrapper = styled.div`
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-family: ${fonts.Gotham};
  font-size: ${fontSizes.sm};
  font-weight: 500;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
`;

const FooterContainer = styled.div`
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
`;


const Footer = (props) => {
  return (
    <FooterWrapper>
      <FooterContainer>
        <LinkFooter to="/">Privacy & Policy</LinkFooter>
        <Beuter2020>© 2020 THE BEUTER</Beuter2020>
        <LinkFooter to="/">Facebook</LinkFooter>
      </FooterContainer>
    </FooterWrapper>
  );
};
```

p/s: I am using styled-components

After took out `position: absolute, bottom:0`
[image]

Here is my project Github:
https://github.com/nathannewyen/the-beuter

Comment: You are using `position: absolute` on your footer. You need to take that out as well as `bottom: 0`. Using absolute removes the footer from the page's normal flow. So, take it out and you should be fine.

Comment: If I took it  out it will overwrite my navbar. Because I have top-navbar and side-navbar `position:fixed`. I just added an image if I took it out

Comment: Ok then. You probably need to show us all your CSS for more insight.

Comment: Here is my github: https://github.com/nathannewyen/the-beuter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change position absolute to fixed(absolute is wrong because of when u scroll the page absolute footer also scroll)

make sure footer is in root element, otherwise parent style applied to footer like padding
in this situation you should mention css clearly

```
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
```

becuase of padding

you did right but the actual problem is position

```css
.footer{
padding: 10px 0;
  font-weight: 500;
left:0;
right:0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  
  }
```

```html
<div>
dffd
df
f
df
fd
fd
f
df

df
df
d
f
df
df
d
f
df
df
d
fd
f
df
d
fd
f
f
df
d
f
df
d
fd
ff
fd
f
df
df
fd
f
f
dfd
fd
f
d
fdf
d
f
f
df
df
d
f
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
df
fd
f
dfd
<br>
f
df
d
f
dfd
f
df
df
d
f
df
d
f
dffaffsdfsfdffdfdfdfdf
</div>

<div class="footer">
something
</div>
```

without sticky footer(main element occupied height:100vh so your footer automatically goes down after 100vh )

```css
.main{
min-height:100vh;
width:100%;
}
.footer{

background:red;
height:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
main


</div>


<div class="footer">footer</div>
```

Comment: How can I just make it stay bottom not trying to make it stick when I scroll ?

Comment: just add footer wrapper position absolute to relative, if you dont want  sticky.